# Use FastRTPS in Docker with ROS2 Galactic

Tags: ros2, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am using the offical ros:galactic image and I am trying to use FastRTPS.
When I run `export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp` it does complain about fast_rtps not beeing installed.
Is it not installed in the offical Ros Galactic image?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394790/use-fastrtps-in-docker-with-ros2-galactic/) by [fnax8902](https://answers.ros.org/users/73234/fnax8902/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2022-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Galactic, Cyclone is the default RMW. The Docker images do not come with FastRTPS preinstalled, no.

See also #q378063 (that doesn't mention Docker, but it's the same set of files).

You'll have to install `ros-galactic-rmw-fastrtps-cpp`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1